Isekai manhwa where the main character is thrown into a game world and reaches an ending every time he marries the female lead
I'm looking for a full color manhwa I read a few months ago (don't remember, but it must have started as early as 2022 and as late as late 2023-early 2024) where a guy is thrown into a game in which he plays the role of three different male characters with three different female leads (with very similar, if not the same, names) and he has to IIRC become king or something to finish the game. Just marrying the female lead also gives him an ending, although the marriage ending makes him reset and switch to another body.
The female leads varied in their background and occupation. The first one is a farm girl with long brown hair. The second one is a daughter of a knight with short white hair (and even loses an arm in one of the resets). The third one is the bastard daughter of some noble/royal (and an actual child) with long blonde hair. I'm not sure if there's a fourth one.
IIRC their stories go something like this:

The farm girl is a saintess that would end up getting tortured to death or something if she goes to the church.
The knight girl dies in the same war each time (except when she gets married) (and when she doesn't die but loses an arm because of the main character).
The bastard child girl is actual royalty, but she's thrown in the streets and either dies of poisoning/illness or becomes a mob boss (for some reason).

Also, the main character gets skills from his past runs sent to his next one, so he gets strong enough to become a mob boss for the third girl, but the first time he does it, she ends up becoming a mob boss herself.
Also, in the third girl's route, there's this woman that gave them housing when they first met her, but she fell in love with the main character in his first run, so she's in love in all subsequent resets, because for some reason that's the "gift" he got from that run (which IIRC is the same one where the bastard child girl becomes a mob boss).

Found it. The name was Desperately Making Her a Princess or Raising the Princess After Her Death. The girl's name was Lena.

The long-term public service exam candidate, Minseo, finds himself trapped in the game, “Raising Lena” as he tries to escape his grim reality. In the game, Minseo becomes a character named Leo, and he must navigate through a world with three different scenarios to accomplish his mission of turning the protagonist, Lena, into a princess. However, the game “Raising Lena” boasts an overwhelming level of difficulty due to enemies who are set to thwart Minseo with their immense power and influence. Will Minseo be able to complete the game by making Lena a princess and return to reality?


Hi, please don't forget to accept your own answer.

Which you can do by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].
